# SAS studio / SQL, how to count and sum the columns and create a new column to store them?

Tags: sql, sas-studio

[image: Dataset]

This is the data set, what I want to do is to count how many Yes in each row, like the first row has 3 Yes so in my new column called Product_Held will have "3".

Answer (score 0):

In SQL, you can use:

```
proc sql;
    select t.*,
           ( (case when bank_account = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end) +
             (case when credit_card = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end) +
             . . . 
           ) as num_yeses
    from t;
```

You can create a view using:

```
proc sql;
    create view <viewname> as
        select t.*,
               ( (case when bank_account = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end) +
                 (case when credit_card = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end) +
                 . . . 
               ) as num_yeses
        from t;
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but is this able to update the table? or just to create view? If I would like to add a new column with this what can i do?

Comment: @Alvin . . . This runs a query which produces a result set that has a new column with the value.  That appears to be what your question is asking for.

Comment: But how i can add the view column to my dataset? So sorry I am a new to programming